# Issue in handling dropdown in protractor using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, xpath, protractor, ui-automation

I am having issues in selecting dropdown in protractor

My Dom looks like this

[image: Dropdown Dom]

This is the XPath to select the dropdown with value Yes

```
//label[contains(text(),"is your family safe?")]//parent::app-control-header//following-sibling::select//option[contains(text(),'Yes')]
```

The following is the way I am trying to select the drop down with the XPath above

First I created an XPath which retrieves the select block and stored in dropDownBlock as below

```
dropDownBlock = element(by.xpath('//label[contains(text(),"is your family safe?")]//parent::app-control-header//following-sibling::select'));

FamilysafeDropdown () {        
    selectDropdownByText(dropDownBlock, "yes");
}
```

I created a function which accepts the element finder and string and selects the value based on the string passed

```
public selectDropdownByText(dropdownElement: ElementFinder, text: string) {
    dropdownElement.click();
    dropdownElement.element(by.xpath('//option[contains(text(), "' + text + '")]')).click();
}
```

My problem here is the code is always finding the element with xpath

`//option[contains(text(), "Yes")]"` and there are multiple dropdowns in my DOM with this XPath.

so I wanted to select value with XPath

```
//label[contains(text(),"is your family safe?")]//parent::app-control-header//following-sibling::select//option[contains(text(),'Yes')]
```

I don't understand the problem here, can someone point me in the right way.

Comment: Could you clarify that there are multiple answers containing the value 'yes' in the dropdown? I believe that is what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the xpath used in following code line:

`dropdownElement.element(by.xpath('//option[contains(text(), "' + text + '")]')).click();`

You should use `.//option[contains(text(), "' + text + '")]`, the prefix `.` at here means search HTML element start from `dropdownElement`.

Without the `.`, it means search HTML element start from the beginning of the HTML page.

In XPath, `.` represents current node.